# Reduce several large tab delimited matrices based on rows and columns using awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have several very large (several gigabytes) tab delimited files with named rows (4.5e6 rows) and columns (ranging from 10 to several hundred).

Ie.
**InputFile1.txt**

```
            A           B           C          D
Row1        1           2           1          3
Row2        2           4           5          3
Row3        3           6           6          4
Row4        4           8           9          4
Row5        5           2           0          1
```

**InputFile2.txt**

```
            E           F           G        
Row1        7           1           5          
Row2        7           5           5          
Row3        6           4           7          
Row4        5           4           8          
Row5        4           9           0
```

I also have two index files, one for rows and one for columns. Ie:

**IndexRows.txt** (all of these rows are going to be in all files)

```
Row1
Row3
Row4
```

**IndexCols.txt** (no duplicate columns across the files)

```
B
C
F
```

I want to efficiently extract the rows and columns specified in the in the index files from the tab delimited files and then merge all the columns into one file. I'm experienced with R and would be able to do this using R, but these files are very large and using R would be pushing the limits/if possible at all.

Can anyone suggest an efficient way to do this, **using bash/awk**?

In this example, output would look like this:

```
            B       C       F  
Row1        2       1       1
Row3        6       6       4
Row4        8       9       4
```

Thanks

Comment: "Reduce according to the rows and columns ... "  can you elaborate please?  what does `according to` mean in your context?.   Can you also explain what your final output should look like?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear! I mean removing the redundant columns and rows (ie. the rows and columns not in the index files). I've updated the post with this and an example.

Comment: Can you get rid of all those `...`s and simply show us concrete, testable input and output? We get it that there's more rows and columns than show, we just want some small example to clarify your requirements and test a possible solution against.

Comment: Hi Ed, thanks for the suggestion. I've updated my post to include a testable input/output.

Comment: Good. Given what you have now posted my suggested solution is wrong as I completely misunderstood your requirements so I'm going to delete it.

Comment: Sorry about that. Hope it is clear now. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I'm still hoping to find a solution to this using awk rather than R. Any suggestions on how to attract more people to see this?

Answer (score 1):

I would approach the problem as follows.

```
library(data.table)

DT   <- fread(f.txt,          sep="\t",  header=TRUE)
ROWS <- fread(file_rows.txt,  sep="\t",  header=FALSE)
COLS <- fread(file_cols.txt,  sep="\t",  header=FALSE)

setkey(DT, id)
setkey(ROWS) # sets key to the single column

## Note that this filters DT to only those rows with `id` in ROWS$V1
DT[ROWS]
```

#### Finally, to filter columns and rows:

```
DT[ROWS, .SD, .SDcols=COLS$V1]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've not tried data.table/fread. I only know base R has a very hard time handling large (2+GB) files. Do you have good experience with data.table and 2+GB files?

Comment: yep, handles them easily.